# date format in .net - how do I say use the given cultureinfo?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

WHen using the CultureInfo to render a number, #,000.00 does not literally mean place a , for the thousands separator and a . for the decimal. It means use the correct character from that culture at those locations.

However, using "mm-dd-yyyy" places the month, day, year in that order regardless of culture. Is there a way to tell it I'm passing the US format but change to match the passed in culture?

More details:

```
CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(1955, 9, 26);
string displayValue = BIRTHDAY.tOsTRING("M/d/yyyy", ci);
```

Comment: @MitchWheat - sorry, I added a short code sample to illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx)  instead of hard coded string.

```
var text = date1.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")
  .DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: I forgot to add another issue we face. This is for our reporting system where we let people select the format they wish to use. I was hoping there is a way to let them define it using a format string that we then convert.

Comment: @DavidThielen, not sure what your problem then... If user picked "use culture specific format" (howevere you want to represent it in UI) than use ShortDatePattern (or Long,...) otherwise if full format specified - use it as is. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: good point. I'll add those as options along with the explicit formats.